# Pointer in Java

Tags: java

I have a 450*300 image. Buttons are distributed on that image based on some rules. Each button  suppose to cost only one pixel, (271,28) and (272,28) represent two different buttons. I wanna track existing button with its x,y location. Intuitively, I thought it's convenient and O(1) complexity to access the Button on image by subscript, so I try to use a 2-dimensional array.

```
JButton[][] btnArray= new JButton[450][300];
```

As button numbers are limited within 100, so that's not what I want to do which allocate unnecessary redundant space. I just need 450*300 pointers, pointing to some specific JButton instance or being null. Can I implement such mechanism in Java?

Thanks, enjoy fool's day tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JButton[][] btnArray= new JButton[450][300];
```

In fact, this statement allocated 2-d array for JButton references instead of JButton objects.
It has been done indeed.

Comment: thanks RollingBoy, can this theory apply to C++(regardless of the syntax)? I suppose in C++ compiler would call the constructor and hence create JButton ojects.

Comment: They're differenct. For objects, Java only supports array of references while C++ supports array of pointers and array of objects.

Comment: @SSB: C++ objects and Java objects have pretty much **nothing** in common. :\

Answer (score 2):

Actually `JButton[][] btnArray= new JButton[450][300];` does not create/allocate memory for  450*300 buttons. you are just creating 450*300 reference variables.

you can create button instances as needed

```
btnArray[5][5] = new JButton("5, 5");
```

and everything else that's not initialized like this would be null.

Answer (score 1):

I think, to avoid cresting a large array of null references, I would be tempted to, instead, initiliase a Map of buttons keyed on location, e.g. using `Point` as the key.

```
Map<Point, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<Point, JButton>();
```

Finding out whether a button exists at a given location is now a simlle map operation

```
buttons.Contains(new Point(123, 456));
```

And the map key set gives you the list of locations.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done there *is* allocating space for 450x300 pointers since reference variables in Java are effectively pointers. You now just need to go through and initialise them with object references or null.

Answer (score 0):

If you're limited to 100 buttons, instead of creating an array of length 450*300 = 135000, why not create an array of length 100 (or even an `ArrayList` so it only uses as much memory as you have allocated buttons) that stores an object containing the `JButton` and its x and y coordinates in the image. It all depends on whether memory usage or speed is more important for your application.